# How to use update and delete query in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

First i write manually update, delete, insert and select query and execute data with `mysql_query` function

Like this:

Select query

```
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
$postSql = "SELECT DISTINCT post_id
            FROM " . $prefix . "postmeta As meta
            Inner Join " . $prefix . "posts As post
            On post.ID = meta.post_id
            Where post_type = 'product' 
            And post_status = 'publish'
            And meta_key Like '%product_img%'";
$postQry = mysql_query($postSql);
while ($postRow = mysql_fetch_array($postQry)) {
     $post_id = $postRow['post_id'];
}
```

Insert Query

```
$insert_images = "Insert Into " . $prefix . "postmeta(post_id,meta_key,meta_value) Value('$post_id','$meta_key','$data_serialize')";
        mysql_query($insert_images);
```

Update Query:

```
$update_price = "Update " . $prefix . "postmeta
                         Set meta_key = 'wpc_product_price'
                         Where post_id = $supportMetaID
                         And meta_key Like '%product_price%'";
 mysql_query($update_price);
```

Delete Query

```
mysql_query("Delete From " . $prefix . "postmeta Where meta_key IN ('product_img1','product_img2','product_img3')");
```

All queries are working perfectly ... but now i want to embed all queries in wordpress queries.

I can also use wordpress queries like

```
$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
$wpdb->insert( 
    'table', 
    array( 
        'column1' => 'value1', 
        'column2' => 123 
    ), 
);
$wpdb->update( 
    'table', 
    array( 
        'column1' => 'value1',  // string
        'column2' => 'value2'   // integer (number) 
    ), 
    array( 'ID' => 1 )
);
$wpdb->delete( 'table', array( 'ID' => 1 ) );
```

But you can see that i use `and / or` conditions in my queries. So any body help me how can i embed my queries in wordpress

Comment: Have you heard about `$wpdb->prepare`. Please have a look https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb.

Comment: hmmmm ok i'll try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$wpdb->prepare` for the queries involving different criteria

```
$wpdb->query( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "Update " . $prefix . "postmeta
         Set meta_key = %s
         Where post_id = %d
         And meta_key Like '%product_price%'" ,
         'wpc_product_price',$supportMetaID 
        )
);
```

Also if your are inserting/deleting from postmeta is suggest you to use WP's builtin functions [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)/[delete_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta)

Comment: insert and delete query also use with prepare

Comment: @deemi yes use prepare but its better to use WP's builtin functions

Comment: i know i prefer to use wp function .. but now in this canerio i must use custom quries

Answer (score 2):

Well you can do it the wordpress way and all the **security issues** are already taken care by wordpress.

**Adding/updating a post meta is as simple as**

```
update_post_meta( $post_id , 'key', 'value');
```

**Fetching the post meta is as simple as**

```
 get_post_meta( $post_id , 'key', TRUE);
```

(Here true will return as a single variable, if you are expecing an array use FALSE.)

**Deleting a post meta is simple as**

```
delete_post_meta($post_id , 'key');
```